# Angle problem between points on a unit sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

I am dealing with an applied question with space angles correction but have no clue.
The question: Given n points are denoted by $\{V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_{n-1},V_n\}$ on the unit sphere whose center is at the original point $O$. The projections of $\{\vec{OV_1},\ldots,\vec{OV_n}\}$ onto the $XOY$ plane sorted counterclockwise. Now there is a point $V_{n+1}$. It is known that the angle between the vector $\vec{OV_1}$ and the vector $\vec{OV_{n+1}}$ is $\alpha_1$. And the $n-1$ angles between vector $\vec{OV_{n+1}}$ and vectors $\{\vec{OV_2},\ldots\vec{OV_n}\}$ are denoted by $\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$. Then I want to ask what are the relationships between the $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$ and what are the range of the $\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$. I am confused about using angles to describe the spatial position of points. Thank you so much for your attention and answers.

Comment: Think in terms of scalar products (cosines of the angles) instead of angles themselves. Then you'll just have a bunch of linear expressions in terms of the coordinates of the new vector with coefficients determined by the old ones and if you remember your linear algebra and elementary analytic geometry, you should be able to finish from there :-)

Answer (score 1):

> It is known that the angle between the vector $\vec{OV_1}$ and the
> vector $\vec{OV_{n+1}}$ is $\alpha_1$.

Ok, so $$\textbf{V}_{n+1}\cdot \textbf{V}_1 = \cos(\alpha_1).$$

> And the $n-1$ angles between vector $\vec{OV_{n+1}}$ and vectors $\{\vec{OV_2},\ldots\vec{OV_n}\}$ are denoted by $\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$.

Meaning
$$ \textbf{V}_{n+1}\cdot \textbf{V}_{k} = \cos(\alpha_k),$$
$k=1,\dots,n$.

> Then I want to ask what are the relationships between the $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$...

Well, for example, the difference between $\alpha_k$ and $\alpha_l$ will be
$$ \delta \alpha_{k l} = \cos^{-1}(\textbf{V}_{n+1}\cdot \textbf{V}_{k})- \cos^{-1}(\textbf{V}_{n+1}\cdot \textbf{V}_{l}). $$

> ... and what are the range of the $\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$.

Your points are sorted only in the XOY plane, so it is not obvious to me that there's any simple way to get the max or minimum $\alpha$ by just selecting the correct two $\textbf{V_k}$ and comparing them with $V_{n+1}$. Depending on your application, it may be suitable to just brute force calculate the maximum and minimum of $\alpha_k = \cos^{-1}(\textbf{V}_{n+1}\cdot \textbf{V}_k). $ across all $k$.